# css not function on input submit in php/html

Tags: html, css

I have a form and the input submit I cant styling.
I want that the button looks like a text and with hover change background and font colour.
Any solving?

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: made, mirage;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: none;
  background-color: #383e42;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="yourmail" placeholder="Váš e-mail:">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Předmet:">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Text správy" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send-mail" id="" value="Odeslat" />
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The border around the button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your CSS styles in a `<style></style>` element.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="yourmail" placeholder="Váš e-mail:">
                        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Předmet:">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Text správy" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="send-mail" id="" value="Odeslat"/>
                    </form>
<style>
    input[type="submit"] {
        font-family: made, mirage;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: none;
        background-color: #383e42;
    }

    input[type="submit"]:hover{
        background-color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: the css has the own file and source link in php ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

Answer (score 0):

To make the button look like normal text:

- Set `background-color` to `unset`
- Set `border-style` to `none`

Then, on hover, simply change background and text color.

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  border-style: none;
  font-family: made, mirage;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: unset;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #383e42;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="yourmail" placeholder="Váš e-mail:">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Předmet:">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Text správy" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send-mail" id="" value="Odeslat" />
</form>
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your solution. The hover here is functional and if i make a different file or save the same as html it is function but not in php file- I do not have idea why.